# Check whether element in a list is the first

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a list and I'm using jQuery to allow for list objects to be removed.

```
$(document).off('click', '#delete').on('click', '#delete',function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

I was wondering how do I tell if the element being deleted is the first on the list?

Comment: Id must be unique. so your HTML is invalid if there's more than 1 `#delete`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ah yes, thanks for that. I will fix this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `.index()` position. This function returns a zero based index so, for the first element, you get 0. Another interesting point is that 0, in javascript, is `false` and all other numbers are `true`. The `.index()` function, then, returns `false` if the element is the first element.

```
$(document).off('click', '#delete').on('click', '#delete',function(e) {
    if(!$(this).parent().index()){
        //the element is the first element
    }
});
```

[This is the full DOC for the `.index()` function.](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: This solution will work, but IMO the readability of the conditional suffers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

So it would be something like:

```
if($(this).parent().is(':first')) {
    // this was the first element
}
```

Comment: and how do you know the first item is the current one?

Comment: I edited my answer. The one he is removing in his example is `$(this).parent()` so just check if it is the first.

Comment: That will always return true. `this` is a single element. `parent` return 1 element. `:first` check if it's the first of the jQuery Object.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I was just using the element the guy asking the question was removing and that was `$(this).parent()`

Comment: @edhedges That is fine to reuse the code, but the `is(':first')` part is erroneous since it will always return true. When there is only 1 element in a jQuery stack, that element is always first.

Comment: Actually, im running test and `is(':first')` always return false. It is not a selector to compare, but a filter one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is` method:

```
if ($(this).parent().is(':first-child'))
{
}
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: This isn't the same element he is removing. See my answer.